# List image is empty

Tags: android, image, listview

i'm having some trouble with my code app: i'm trying to display in an activity a list of image taken from an array but when i try to execute the app i've an empty list without error in debug. Can anyone help me? Here is my activity:

```
String [] vett;
ListView list;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_techpuno);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    vett=intent.getExtras().getStringArray("nomeImmagine");
    for(int i = 0;i<vett.length;i++){
    Log.d("test", vett[i]);}


    //list.setListAdapter(new AdapterTecniche(this, vett));
 list.setAdapter(new AdapterTecniche(this, R.layout.activity_techp,vett));
}
```

And here it is the adapter:

```
public class AdapterTecniche extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final int resource;
private final String[] img;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    LayoutInflater inflater;

public AdapterTecniche(Context context,int resource, String[]img) {
    // your code
    super(context, R.layout.activity_techpuno);
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.context = context;
this.resource=resource;
    this.img=img;
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(getContext().getApplicationContext());
        }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ViewHolder viewHolder;

   View rowView = convertView;


    if(rowView == null) {
        Log.d("errore","Immagini non presenti");
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.immagini, parent, false);
    viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.imageView=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
    rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else
    {

    viewHolder=(ViewHolder)rowView.getTag();
    }

    if(img==null){
        Log.d("errore","Immagini non presenti");
    }else{

    int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(img[position],"drawable", context.getPackageName());
    for(int i=0;i<img.length;i++){
        Log.d("err", img[i]);
    }
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(resourceId, viewHolder.imageView);


    }
    return rowView;
    }
static class ViewHolder {
ImageView imageView;
}
}
```

Immagini.xml (each image layout)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_image"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And Activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: maybe is a layout problem, check that the list and list items doesn't have zero height; could you post also the xml layout files?

Comment: yes now i edit the first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_techpuno);`

should be before

`list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);`

Because Activity firstly need to have binded/inflated layout, after that you can "find" your views from it.

Edit
Use `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)` constructor to give objects to it. 
Or override `getCount()` because your adapter have no idea how many items he got.

Comment: i've changed my code but again nothing on the screen  and no error. Now i change my code in my previous post

Comment: U are using wrong constructor for `ArrayAdapter`, because `ArrayAdapter` has no idea about items and what is the count of them....

Comment: No changes? still i see `super(context, R.layout.activity_techpuno);`